# Multiple set wise where

Tags: sqlite

I want to change two fields in one table with one query. It's looks like this

```
UPDATE SavedStoreModel 
SET storePosition =:secondItemPosition 
WHERE storePosition =:firstItemPosition, 
storePosition =:firstItemPosition 
WHERE storePosition =:secondItemPosition
```

But this query is don't executable because of coma. A query like this works fine without where condition, but how to do this with multiple where?

Comment: Normally you would use 2 queries. Nothing wrong with that. Why the need for just one? It is possible though

Comment: It should be in one query, because I'm swiping to elements

Comment: This is not a valid sql statement. Post sample data and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE SavedStoreModel 
SET storePosition = case when storePosition = :firstItemPosition 
                         then :secondItemPosition 
                         else :firstItemPosition 
                    end
WHERE storePosition in (:firstItemPosition, :secondItemPosition)
```